# Рекурсивный вывод списка через итератор

Tags: java

Написал метод, который должен выводить через рекурсию(используя итератор коллекции) все элементы списка разделенные заданным знаком в виде строки. Например есть список, который содержит числа от 1 до 5. При вызове метода join должен этот список выводится в формате "1+2+3+4+5". Вообщем-то метод работает, но почему-то в результате я получаю "1+2+3+4+5+". Где я ошибся, что у меня выводится после 5 еще один плюс?

```
    public static String join(List values, String separator) {
        return join(values.iterator(), separator);
    }

    public static String join(Iterator values, String separator) {

        if (!values.hasNext()) return "";

        String firstElement = values.next() + separator;    // Первый элемент списка
        String restElements = join(values, separator);
        return firstElement + restElements;
    }
```

Comment: Походу сессия началась посыпались школьные вопросы =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Замени

```
String firstElement = values.next() + separator;
```

на

```
String firstElement = values.next() + (values.hasNext() ? separator : "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь тем, что если список не пустой, в вывод можно сразу добавить первый элемент, и потом добавлять к нему все остальные через разделитель.

```
public static <T> String join(Iterable<T> values, String separator) {
    return join(values.iterator(), separator);
}

public static <T> String join( Iterator<T> values, String separator) {
    if (!values.hasNext()) return "";

    return rec( values, separator, values.next().toString() );
}

private static <T> String rec( Iterator<T> values, String separator, String result ) {
    if ( !values.hasNext() ) return result;
    return rec( values, separator, result + separator + values.next() );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "> " + join( Arrays.asList( "Мама", "мыла", "раму" ), "+" ) );
    System.out.println( "> " + join( Arrays.asList( "Тест" ), "+" ) );
    System.out.println( "> " + join( Arrays.asList(), "+" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо проверять одно из двух:
а) есть к чему прибавлять?
б) есть что прибавлять?

Вашу функцию легко можно переделать под вариант б)

```
public static String join(Iterator values, String separator) {

    if (!values.hasNext()) return "";

    String firstElement = values.next();    // Первый элемент списка
    String restElements = join(values, separator);
    return restElemets.isEmpty() ? firstElement : firstElement + separator + restElements;
}
```

Здесь на каждом шаге проверяется хвост на пустоту.

Для варианта а) функцию можно разбить на две. Одна обычная для первого элемента. Другая рекурсивная для хвоста.

```
public static String join(Iterator values, String separator) {
    if (values.hasNext()) 
        return joinRest(values.next(), values, separator);
    else
        return "";
}

public static String joinRest(String firstElement, Iterator values, String separator) {
    if (values.hasNext())
        return joinRest(firstElement + separator + values.next(), values, separator);
    else
        return firstElement;
}
```

Здесь никаких дополнительных проверок не понадобилось. Второй функции (`joinRest`) всегда будет к чему прибавлять.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том что даже в последний раз вы к значению добавляете сепаратор. И если элементов будет не 5 а допустим миллион, не очень бы хотелось добавлять проверку(а не последний ли это элемент).
Я бы предпочел просто поменять на:

```
String finalString = firstElement + restElements;

return finalString.substring(0, finalString.length() - 1);
```

Так как вам просто нужно убрать последний(лишний) разделитель.